# jQuery SliderTabs pause on hover

Tags: jquery

http://lopatin.github.io/sliderTabs

I'm using this plugin for tabbed slider but I don't know how to add "pause on hover" usually all other plugins have option for it but this one doesn't and I'm not a JS expert.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Did you try something like :

    $("div#mySliderTabs").hover(function() {
     sliderTabs.stop(true, true);
    }

Comment: I just tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: Then try using .preventDefault()